# T-SQL Get First Day of Week from number

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, calendar, datepart

I have a table that we use for our fiscal year which does not match up to the traditional calendar. What I am trying to accomplish is to create a column that keeps the actual SQL calendar date for the first day of a week given the week number.

Example:

```
Fiscal Year     Fiscal Date     Fiscal Week     Calendar Date
2016            1/1/2016        1               1/1/2016
2016            1/2/2016        1               1/1/2016
2016            1/3/2016        1               1/1/2016
2016            1/4/2016        1               1/1/2016
2016            1/5/2016        1               1/1/2016
2016            1/6/2017        1               1/1/2016
2016            1/7/2017        1               1/1/2016
2016            1/8/2017        1               1/1/2016
2016            1/9/2017        2               1/4/2016
```

I was trying to use the following, but I want to provide the opposite:

```
set datefirst 1;
select datepart(week, '2016-01-01');
```

Instead:

```
set datefirst 1;
select datepart(week=1, What is the First Day of week 1)
select datepart(week=2, What is the First Day of week 2)
```

I tried to use the following code as found in another thread, but it doesn't provide the correct first day of the week:

```
set datefirst 1;

Declare @week integer  = 2
Declare @Year Integer  = 2016
declare @date datetime


set @date = Dateadd(week, @week-1, DateAdd(day, 0, 
        DateAdd(month, 0, 
        DateAdd(Year, @Year-1900, 0))))

select @date startweek, DATEADD (D, -1 * DatePart (DW, @date) + 7, @date) endweek
```

As it provides 1/8/2016 as the first day of week 2 when it should be 1/4/2016.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you could save some headache and just create a [calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/) with all the options you may need. Aaron has done most of it for you :)

Comment: We already have a calendar table, we are just trying to find a way to add a first calendar date based on the sql calendar to this table. I guess I could create a temp table and then insert the rows for that temp table for each record, but I figured there should be some way to query it instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @week integer  = 2
Declare @Year Integer  = 2016
declare @date datetime

set @date = Dateadd(week, @week-1, DateAdd(day, 0, DateAdd(month, 0, DateAdd(Year, @Year-1900, 0))))
set @date = dateadd(day, 2 - datepart(dw, @date), @date)

select @date startweek, DATEADD (D, -1 * DatePart (DW, @date) + 7, @date) endweek
```